# Sending and receiving text using android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sms, android-emulator

I'm currently developing android application which includes text messaging. Is it possible to send and receive text messages just by using android emulator? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Take a look on this topic: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android good luck

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It's quite easy:

- open a console
- connect via telnet to the running emulator: `telnet localhost 5554` (you can find the portnumber in the title of the emulator)
- type this: `sms send senderPhoneNumber textmessage`

Comment: @Andi  your answer saved me alot of time +1

Comment: its saying - KO: unknown command, try 'help'

Comment: Sagar Nayak "its saying - KO: unknown command, try 'help' " after "telnet localhost 5554" you should run "auth <your auth token>" then it will work http://stackoverflow.com/a/37503734/2765497

Comment: `telnet` didn't work for me recently. See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/38897485/1065835

Answer (score 10):

You can also use two emulators. Open both emulators simultaneously. They will be named `emulator-5554` and `emulator-5556`.

Then from one device, text (555)521-555x, where the last 4 digits are the number from the emulator name. This will allow you to text between both devices.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Eclipse, its pretty easy. 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI7vZ.png)
1) Goto DDMS.

2) There, the left pane will consist of list of emulators active, select your emulator and then in the right pane you will get Emulator Control->Telephony action-> Incoming Number, Message. Type these and hit send.

3) In your emulator you will receive message.

Cheers :)
[image: DDMS]

Answer (score 5):

If you are working on windows:
1. Install the telnet client via the command prompt by typing

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

2. Type telnet localhost 5554 . Here 5554 is the number that appears in the title of the emulator.

1. Type sms send 1234 "message"

You are done ! Cheers ! Check your emulator for the received message

Answer (score 3):

If you read the emulator documentation, you will see that you can send and receive text messages between the environment within the emulator and the emulator console.

Actually sending them out into the real world would require that you have an sms gateway service somewhere and write something to move traffic between that and the emulator.

Comment: Actually I've tried sending text message using the plugin in eclipse. However, when I tried to send a text message again it suddenly didn't work. I'm thinking if there are any ways in sending text messages in android emulator.

Comment: Did you read the emulator documentation yet?  There's an emulator console that you can connect to via a telnet application (or programmatically) and issue a variety of commands, including sending SMS

Answer (score 3):

open another emulator and check their numbers from the window title ex 5554:emulator name

and just simply type the number(5554) in  "To"  and hit send thats it