# Is it possible to receive an SMS from Android emulator?

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way to receive an SMS from Android emulator, perhaps on a TCP port.
I know it's possible to send SMS to emulator by opening a TCP socket on the emulator port and using "send sms" command, but is it also possible to receive an SMS this way?

I'll elaborate - I have a java application running on a Tomcat server. I also have an Android emulator running on the same machine. I can send SMS messages from the application to the emulator using the "sms send" command. Can I also receive SMS messages in some way?

Answer (score 25):

`telnet localhost <port number>` didn't work for me.

This worked for me:

Run an emulator and click "More." That's three horizontal dots to the right of the emulator window.
[image]

Then click "Phone". 
[image]

Type a phone number from which you'd like to receive a text and the text.
Press "Send message"
[image]

Now you see your message.

[image]

---

**Source:**
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#console, the table "Working with the Extended Controls, Settings, and Help," the row "Phone."

Comment: I believe the question was to ... **receive** an SMS from Android emulator."  This answer very clearly tells how to **send** instead.

Comment: This is the perfect answer for latest version of android studio where DDMS was deprecated. Saved lot of time :)

Answer (score 9):

Friend, refer to this answer provided in a blog (with additional info from [authentication token does not match ~/.emulator_console_auth_token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37812636/461982))

> Just connect the emulator using telnet and there we can emulate SMS. Below are the steps to emulate SMS:
>
> Step 1: Start the emulator (with any desired options). Open a new terminal / command shell and type :

```
adb devices
```

> Note the number after emulator (emulator-5554). This is the port number.
>
> Step 2: Connect to the console using the telnet command:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

> Step 3: You will then need to authenticate the session. Find the auth_token in ~/.emulator_console_auth_token and copy the text in the file. Return to the telnet console and enter:

```
auth {contents_of_token_file}
```

> Step 4: After you have authenticated the shell you can emulate SMS with the command:

```
sms send <phonesender> <textmessage>
```

For More Info Refer to this [link](http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/sms-emulation-on-android.html)

If you send SMS from the emulator, see this http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful, but it only refers to sending sms to emulator. I wonder if there is a way to receive an sms from it.

Comment: Yes, I was asking if it's possible to receive an sms from Android emulator on a PC - not on another emulator.

Comment: @MikeSchem after opening the telnet session, follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/40116835/461982 to authenticate it, then the sms command will be available.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE : follow video tutorial on this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#console

[image: DDMS -> Emulator Control]

[image]
It been a while, but never late to learn.

Comment: Please tell me this screen shot is from what application?

Comment: it is called, android device monitor, I added a screenshot of it, from android studio

Answer (score 3):

in terminal you can use this

```
adb emu sms send [from] [message]


adb emu sms send 12345 hiiiiii
adb emu sms send 09129009090 Hi
```

Answer (score 2):

**No it is not possible.**

first you connect to your emulator via telnet with following command:

```
telnet localhost <console-port>
```

then you can query for help like this, to see all available commands for sms:

```
sms help
```

here is the list with all commands:

```
available sub-commands:
send             send inbound SMS text message
pdu              send inbound SMS PDU
```

finally you can go and visit android developer page for extensive information about emulator console here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#console

Answer (score 1):

Start two emulators, first will be 5554, second will be 5556. Send a text message using the built in messaging app from 5554 to 5556 by typing '5556' as the telephone number.

(You will need to have created two different AVDs first, so that you can use one for 5554 and the other for 5556)

Comment: Thanks, I know it's possible to send messages between emulators, but is it possible to receive the sms message on a pc - maybe a tcp port?

Comment: Works like a charm!  And you don't even have to open any special windows.

Comment: Not quite... Try to send long SMS (more than 160 letters) from one emulator and you will get a piece of junk on other emulator. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119319859