# Sending SMS with Android Emulator through telnet

Tags: android, telnet

I can send SMS to the Android emulator using the telnet command:

sms send

However, the SMS UDH (User data header) is null. How to send a message that will have a UDH on it using the same telnet command?

Something similar to [this.](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/index.php?p=udh) However then I try to send the message from that link using telnet. The supposedly UDH and UDH is showing as part of the message body, which should not be the case.

Comment: My goal is something that will send a "binary data" like MMS and ringtone or some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you need to recieve MMS or something like that, you can use another emulator.

You need 1 more emulator for sending the MMS. So you can whatever you want, as you send from your phone emulator.

You can read more on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726121/212508