# authentication token does not match ~/.emulator_console_auth_token

Tags: android, authentication, command-prompt

I am trying to access android emulator through the console.

Initially I typed `telnet localhost 5554`,then I see:

[image: screenshot of command line]

Next I typed `auth auth_token`, I got the following error:

[image: screenshot of command line]

What is wrong here?

Where can I get this token?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, the file is located in your current user folder

```
c:\Users\<current_user>\.emulator_console_auth_token
```

You can open the file with notepad and copy the token.

Now, you can run

```
auth <token>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just copy the token from inside the file .emulator_console_auth_token and run the command

> auth your-token-here

In order to check if everything went well just run the "help" command, you'll see much more commands available on the list. I don't know if it's the best bet to solve this problem but, this solution worked for me.