# authentication token does not match in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android and using `Android Studio 2.3.3` on `Windows 10`.

When I run android emulator, I choose `Galaxy_Nexus_API_25` with telnet local host 5554, I want to adjust the internet speed by `network speed edge` instruction, but after using telnet it says that I should type `auth <auth_token>` and the key is in the location which it refers.
But when I go to that location and open the file `.emulator_console_auth_token` and copy and paste it like this: `auth <mykey>` 
 , it says:

> "KO: authentication token does not match ~/.emulator_console_auth_token"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please see this link -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40116835/8199772

Comment: thank you but my problem is something else, I copy and paste the key which is exactly written in that notepath file, but for example I write :      
 "auth <3pOBDC5DXkuWFTLL>"  but when I press Enter it says to me :"authentication token does not match ~/.emulator_console_auth_token" and I don`t know why

Comment: Try running the`help` command. See if it gives you more info

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue recently. I resolved it by deleting the .emulator_console_auth_token file and restarting the emulator to generate a new auth token which worked.

I believe it is caused by using multiple emulator and the auth key doesnt get updated for the 2nd device so you end up using an auth key meant for a different emulated device.