# Simulating incoming call in regression test (robotium)?

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I'm using robotium to test my app. Part of its functionality involves its behaviour when receiving an incoming call. Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to simulate this programmatically in the test case.

I'm thinking it's got to be possible or else any app that relies on incoming/outgoing call events couldn't be regression tested.

Comment: If you have a physical device with a mobile number and you need to do incoming calls, you could go to https://mail.google.com, login to your Google account, and click the "Call Phone" link on the left hand side. I do not know anything about how to simulate an incoming call, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, incoming calls etc. can't be simulated using Robotium. They can be however by the emulator, using telnet. See this post: [Sending and receiving text using android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325669/sending-and-receiving-text-using-android-emulator)