# Android Test Automation tools

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests

I need a tool to automate testing of my android application. Specially I want to cover the test cases below:

- send 10 sms
- make a photo
- make 10 calls

It's even more like a script, which will allow me to record actions.

Any hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should take a look at [Monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

I'm pretty sure it's exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

There are three options you can look at: [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/), [Scirocco](http://code.google.com/p/scirocco/) and [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org).

I've found them to be useful for basic operations as long as you are explicit in what should happen and what to click on, etc.  I cannot say whether they can send SMSes using the built-in SMS app, it is likely that you will need to build this automation in somehow, or even [send SMSes via the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325669/sending-and-receiving-text-using-android-emulator).

Comment: I guess all this tools are for Unit-testing android apps. What I need is a tool to record specific actions performed outside my app.

Comment: Your Roboelectric link doesn't work for me. Is it this? http://robolectric.org/

Comment: Also, looks like the name doesn't have the first 'e'; the website calls it *Robolectric*.

Comment: Looks like they moved. Link fixed

Answer (score 1):

What about Android testing framework?
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html