# Automation testing tools for android apps

Tags: android, unit-testing, automation, android-testing

I had done automation testing in my android application, I used [**robotium**](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) framework. 
Still I wish to get hands on other automation tools. 
So, could somebody suggest any other free available automation tools for android applications and which is the best one??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Test Automation tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237314/android-test-automation-tools)

Comment: You can also try these open source tools for Android automation : Appium, espresso, calabash & selendroid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have an eye on [**this Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237574/1450401) . it will give you information about other tools

Also [**Monkeyrunner**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

[Scirocco](http://code.google.com/p/scirocco/) and 
[RoboElectric.](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/)