# How to set emulator phone number in my eclipse code file?

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, phone-number, eclipse-adt

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krSFS.png)

I am not able to send and receive SMS between 2 emulators. Where and how can I add the emulator phone numbers in my codes to send text messages?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to send the SMS to the AVD number. For example : `5554`, thats all I do and its working.

The AVD number is on top of your AVD's window.

More source : [Sending and receiving text using android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325669/sending-and-receiving-text-using-android-emulator)

And I've used this source when I was learning:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: I tried adding the number on 1 of the emulator and the 2nd emulator didnt receive any text. Thanks for the source but it looks like its about sending messages from the computer to the emulator.

Comment: Try to add the permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>

Comment: yes i did.     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

Comment: Do you try the reverse? Try to send the SMS from the 2nd to the 1st and see what happened :D. And it might be worth to check the new link in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the new link you've sent! however im getting unknown errors like yellow underlined codes which i cant seem to get rid of:(

Comment: sorry for the long response. Could you please update your question with your "yellow underlined codes"? (well, it should be a warning). Have you tried to follow the tutorial? :D

Comment: Its ok:) I just updated my Q with a picture link for the error. And there was no declaration for R in the sample. however i had to declare R file while working on the sample. import com.example.smsmessaging.R; I assumed that that's the way to declare it yet its wrong.