# Send sms through android emulator and get it in mysql database or post it to a url/php script

Tags: android, apache, android-studio, android-emulator, sms-gateway

I am working on a android application which can send a SMS to a predefined no. I want that, the **SMS send by mobile will receive by My apache server**.

I surf net a lot. There are many services which provides-

1. A virtual no to send sms
2. When virtual no received a sms, it posted(May be Get Request) this to a predefined URL and data may be processed further.

*These services are **not free**.*

I just **want to test all this on my local machine with Android Emulator, Apache Server and whatever needed**.

Comment: You cant send SMS with emulator ! OR you need to connect it with telnet.

Comment: There must be a some procedure to test all this stuff.
I have checked this one already 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325669/sending-and-receiving-text-using-android-emulator?answertab=active#tab-top
I want to post that sms to a url.