# Android console: authentication required

Tags: android

I am trying to run the geo fix command but I am unable to do so because I am greeted by the following message:

Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth ' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your  in
'/Users/me/.emulator_console_auth_token'

I am on a mac [new user] and I do not know how to access the .emulator_console_auth_token file to delete it.

I have tried ~/Users to get to the users folder but it is returning no results. Additionally, the folder with my name does not contain that file. Please help.

Answer (score 34):

You need to take key from this file.
On Mac OS this file is hidden by default.

open terminal, run command:

```
nano ~/.emulator_console_auth_token
```

and copy token from opened file (token look like: mEKb+d0DA2x9eHaK)

Connect to Emulator (if does not connected yet):

1) Check the Port of emulator:

```
adb devices
```

2) Connect to Emulator:

```
telnet localhost <number of port like 5554>
```

you should see:

> " Authentication required Android Console: type 'auth ' to
>   authenticate Android Console: you can find your in
>   '/Users/me/.emulator_console_auth_token'"

3) Set Auth Token:

```
auth <your auth token>
```

Now you can run:

```
geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>
```

or

```
sms send <phonesender> <textmessage>
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to get to the token. When I type /Users/me/.emulator_console_auth_token in my finder it says no results. Am I missing something? A package perhaps? Is the file hidden? If yes, how can I "un-hide" it? What are my options? Grrr!!!

Comment: kyzen - On Mac OS this file is hidden type in terminal command: "nano ~/.emulator_console_auth_token" it will open this hidden file, as alternative you can make hidden files visible, instruction: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-funter-3520878/ or you can install "Commander One" file manager there can find "show hidden files option (button)

Comment: What to do if you get `Command not found: auth`? Can't find anything on google...

Comment: I get Forbiden binary request on set "auth <key>" and putty exits.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, if the "telnet" stage works as it should, you'll actually open a connection with your emulator. The `auth` command is a command that lives in your emulators environment so it's ok you don't have it on your regular terminal environment.

Comment: Help, please! When I use `Putty` to connect to Android emulator after each `Enter` key pressed Putty is closed! So I cannot do anything.

Comment: @Mahdi I also had "Forbiden binary request"  (@BambinoUA you can set Close window on exit to Never to see the error message). I managed to fix that by changing "Telnet negotiation mode" to "Passive" in Telnet settings.

Answer (score 8):

The best thing you can do is:

1. Go to the file .emulator_console_auth_token
2. Open it.
3. Delete the content, let it in blank.
4. Restart your terminal
5. Type again: telnet 127.0.0.1 **port_number(5554)**

Example: `telnet 127.0.0.1 5554`

Comment: Why exactly is circumventing a security feature _the best thing_ one can do?

Comment: coz the security feature is pointless if it's just a temporary emulator on a dev machine. who is going to hack into my emulator to get my valuable (hello_world.apk)s?