# Where does ~/.emulator_console_auth_token come from?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

What process or user action leads to creation of `.emulator_console_auth_token` in the home directory? And, if I delete it, is there an official way to create this file again?

If you don't get the context of the question, you can use ( [Android console: authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442566/android-console-authentication-required/37503734) ) for the reference.

Answer (score 7):

See here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console

> If that file doesn't exist, the telnet localhost console-port command creates the file, which contains a randomly generated authentication token. To disable authentication, delete the token from the .emulator_console_auth_token file or create an empty file if it doesn't exist.