# I am trying to send a sms to an emulator.But it is not working

Tags: android, terminal

I connected to the Emulator using telnet localhost 5554. It said OK. 
But When I try to send an sms using the command "sms send 131212 blablabla" it is giving me the following error.

"KO: unknown command, try 'help'"

Cannot understand why?Please help.
Also, how to send a similar sms to my personal phone connected to the pc?

Comment: A comment on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4325836/6598100) suggests running auth <your auth token>. That should fix the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your home directory and open the file ".emulator_console_auth_token". It will contain a token. (This file is created when you telnet into the emulator)
- Now run the command

  auth your_token

You should be able to send sms to emulator without the error.